# Is it haram to listen to music?

Tags: halal-haram, music

I have a habit of listening to music while I work because it improves my concentration and generally relaxes me a little more.

My mum dislikes my habit and says listening to music is haram, but my question is asking if it is actually haram?

If it is, is there any evidence to support that?

Answer (score -3):

### In the name of Allah, the Beneficent, Most Merciful

**All praise and thanks are due to Allah, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in God from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever Allah guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but Allah, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**Your question:** Is haram to listen to music?

**Answer:** Yes, listening to music and singing is a sin and cause for the sickening and weakening of the heart. The majority of the scholars of the Salaf are unanimous that listening to music and singing and using musical instruments is Haram (prohibited). Evidence that Music is haram:

Allah Says:

> "And incite [to senselessness] whoever you can among them with your voice and assault them with your horses and foot soldiers and become a partner in their wealth and their children and promise them." But Satan does not promise them except delusion." [[**The Night Journey, 17:64**](https://quran.com/17/64)]

It was narrated that Mujaahid (may Allah have mercy on him) said: **“And befool them gradually those whom you can among them with your voice”** – his voice [the voice of Iblees/devil] is singing and falsehood.

> "And of the people is he who buys the amusement of speech to mislead [others] from the way of Allah without knowledge and who takes it in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment." [[**Luqman, 31:6**](https://quran.com/31/6)]

Shaykh Al-Sa’di  said:

> "This includes all manner of haraam speech, all idle talk and falsehood, and all nonsense that encourages kufr and disobedience; the words of those who say things to refute the truth and argue in support of falsehood to defeat the truth; and backbiting, slander, lies, insults and curses; the singing and musical instruments of the devil; and musical instruments which are of no spiritual or worldly benefit." ([Tafseer al-Sa’di, 6/150](https://muflihun.com/articles/music))

The Prophet (pbuh) said **“From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful”** (Imam Al-Bukhari)

Allah Says:

> Say: The things that my Lord hath indeed forbidden are: faahisha (shameful deeds) whether open or secret; sins and trespasses against truth or reason; assigning of partners to Allah for which He hath given no authority; and saying things about Allah of which ye have no knowledge.

If one looks around the society we live in today, one would notice that conventional music is related to almost every place that encourages fahisha or indecency; and it is this concept of fahisha and indecency that Allah has strictly declared haraam for the believers. The principle in Islam is that every road that leads to the forbidden is also forbidden; and as illegal conventional music is an accomplice to and leads or encourages fahisha and indecency, it too would be considered forbidden.

The Prophet (saws) said, **"The distinction between what is lawful and what is unlawful is the song and the tambourine at a wedding."**

The Sixth Imam, Ja'far ibn Muhammad has also stated: **"The playing of the violin promotes the growth of hypocrisy in the heart like water assists the growth of vegetation (algae)."** (Wasa'il ash-Shi'a)

> Abu Hurayrah (RadiyAllahu`anhu) narrated that the Prophet (SallAllahu` alayhi wa sallam) said, what translated means, group of this nation will be transformed into monkeys and swine.” They said, **“Do not they testify that there is no god except Allah and that Muhammed is His Messenger?”** He said, **“Yes. And also they fast pray and perform Hajj.”** They said, **“Then, what is their problem?”** He said, **“They use musical instruments, drums and female singers. (One day) they will go to sleep after a night of drinking and having fun, In the morning, they will be transformed (by Allah) into monkeys and swine.”** [Iughathat Al-Lahfan].

Imam (a.s.) says:

> "If drums and cymbals are played at one's house for forty days, Allah will impose a satan by the name of 'faqandir'. The satans will infiltrate into every cell of the person's body. With the spread of this evil, the person loses all sense of dignity and self-esteem. He will then not care as to what he says or what is said about him. Then, this satan blows into this person. As a result, he becomes utterly shameless. So mush so that he is not concerned or affected even if his women are dishonored." (Wasaelush Shia)

For more informations, please view the list below:

1. [Is Music Really Haram? The Sad Reality of Today's Music.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=c1dafblZJec)
2. [WHY MUSIC IS HARAM - Ibraheem Hussnayn Animated](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=upodJ0m-BF8)
3. [Why is Music Haram & Punishment for Listening to Music By Mufti Menk Q&A](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bfMcuRc8Pdc)
4. [Music haram in Islam? Music forbidden in Islam? Very easy answer to this question](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lC8r8uzzEEM)

**The End**

---

**References:**

- [**Ruling on music, singing and dancing**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5000/ruling-on-music-singing-and-dancing)
- [**Is listening to music is haram????? and i saw in one website that using taf is allowed for womens and it is haram for mens... IS IT TRUE??????????**](http://www.islamhelpline.net/answer/5789/is-listening-to-music-is-haram-and-i-saw-in-one-website-that-using-taf-is-allowed-for-womens-and-it-is-haram-for-mens-is-it-true)
- [**The Status of Music in Islam**](https://www.al-islam.org/articles/status-music-islam-shaykh-saleem-bhimji)
- [**Why is music haram? Evidence that Music is Haram**](http://muhammadnazeefali.com/islam-and-music-why-is-music-haram/)
- [**Fifteenth Greater Sin - MUSIC**](http://www.islamic-laws.com/musicgreatersin.htm)

Comment: please ref and check infor

Comment: The statement: "This depends on what kind of music your listening to" needs elaboration. The statement: "However, you can listen to any kind of music as long as it does not make you commit a sin and as long as it does not involve any evil message." doesn't make sense unless you may explain what you mean. How can Music make you commit a sin? Either you are already sinning by listening (assuming Music is per se haram) or you are using some brain-washing stuff.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Now don’t insult me, I’l edit this one in a proper manner. I thought that anyone know what I was trying to say...

Comment: Insulting??? I try to help you improve your answer... in the hope that you may be able to give an answer of your own which has a basis as the verse you posted is clearly used an evidence against Music being halal.

Comment: @Medi1Saif you have said “brain wash” what does that suppose to mean?

Comment: @Medi1Saif O my God! Sorry for the thing I said with “insulting”, I did not payed attention. But next time I will, and thank you for trying to help me, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Music and singing are different.

Comment: @Crimson Yah well, I was referring that you as an audience, you can go to a singer woman or man as long as they use halal words and not words that encourages you to sin. Music is the result of singing.

Comment: Please let me know why I have got down votes

Comment: Music primarily comes from instruments. And music is not same as singing. Neither do the ahadith prove your claim that you can listen song from grown up woman.

Comment: @Crimson yes but they are used, music is merely a weapon which can be used in bad or good depending on you, just as I said in the answer. The serene is a kind of musical instrument which advertise people to move away, the bell is a kind of musical instrument too.

Comment: You have the wrong definition of "Music". Siren and bell doesn't make music, they make sounds. Sounds are not same as music.

Comment: @Crimson music is divided into sound and voice.